# Color the pixel red in gray-scale image if is greater than some threshold

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

After calculating a pixel-wise difference two grayscale images say img1 and img2, I have to set a certain threshold which is the mean value of diff. Now if the pixels values in img1 > threshold I have to color that pixel as red. How can I color that pixel as red and left other pixels as grayscale? I am familiar to generate a binary mask by assigning pixel-value greater than the threshold as 1 and others as 0 but I want to color that pixel red.

```
img1 = cv2.imread(path,0)
img2 = cv2.imread(path,0)

diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
threshold=int(np.mean(diff))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, starting with:

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('Bean.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('saltnpepperBean.jpg',0)

diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
threshold=int(np.mean(diff))

# Make colour version of input image so we can put red pixels in it
resultRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Colorize all pixels above threshold with red 
resultRGB[diff>3*threshold] = 0,0,255

# Save to disk
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',resultRGB)
```

[image]